# Frozen script at unix socket read with EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) error

Tags: go, sockets, general-network-error

I have this Go connection snippet in a script:

```golang
    d := net.Dialer{Timeout: time.Second * 5}
    c, err := d.Dial("unix", CONFIG.ServiceSocket.Path)
    if err != nil {
        handleFatalError(err, errorString)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    // send message
    message := fmt.Sprintf("{\"action\":\"%s\"}", *Arguments.Action)
    _, err = c.Write([]byte(message))
    if err != nil {
        var errorString = fmt.Sprintf("Write error: %s", err)
        handleFatalError(err, errorString)
    }

    // read response
    buf := make([]byte, CONFIG.ServiceSocket.Buffer)
    n, err := c.Read(buf[:])
    if err != nil {
        var errorString = fmt.Sprintf("Read error: %s", err)
        handleFatalError(err, errorString)
    }
```

But the script gets frozen with the following sequence:

```
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/dhcomms/dispatcher.sock"}, 35) = 0
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, {u32=74057432, u64=139805554509528}}) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX}, [112->2]) = 0
getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/dhcomms/dispatcher.sock"}, [112->35]) = 0
write(3, "{\"action\":\"status\"}", 19) = 19
read(3, 0xc000100000, 1048576)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x6aafd8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0x6aaed8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
epoll_pwait(4, [{EPOLLOUT, {u32=74057432, u64=139805554509528}}], 128, 0, NULL, 0) = 1
epoll_pwait(4,
```

I would like to capture this EAGAIN error and close the program in an orderly manner instead.

How should I achieve that ?

**EDIT** [19/6/23]: Added write/read code

Comment: Your code example has no read or write calls. Where are you actually blocked? (you can't deal with EAGAIN in your code, that is handled by the runtime network poller)

Answer (score -1):

I explain here what I finally did, but I don't like it very much because it seems to me a kind of artificial way to solve the issue.
The program get blocked reading the socket:

```golang
n, err = c.Read(buf[:])
```

So I wrap it inside a go routine with a channel an apply a timeout to the whole thing:

```golang
    var TIMEOUT_READ_SOCKET_UNIX time.Duration = 5
    buf := make([]byte, CONFIG.ServiceSocket.Buffer)
    c1 := make(chan string, 1)
    var n int
    go func() {
        n, err = c.Read(buf[:])
        c1 <- ""
    }()

    select {
    case res := <-c1:
        fmt.Println(res)
        break
    case <-time.After(TIMEOUT_READ_SOCKET_UNIX * time.Second):
        var errorString = "Timeout reading unix socket"
        err := fmt.Errorf("Timeout = %d seconds", TIMEOUT_READ_SOCKET_UNIX)
        handleFatalError(err, errorString)
    }
```

I didn't find the way to apply a timeout to the unix socket when the EAGAIN error happens. I bet this should be the right way. If someone knows how to do that, please...

NOTE: I used go-version 1.20 and I'm newby in Go.

Comment: You can use normal read/write deadlines with a unix socket.